# android remove item from actionbar buttonclick

Tags: android

am having success with this code below but its not what i want.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

       present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            **MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.helpp);
            item.setVisible(false);**

        return true;
    }
```

this code above works but its not how i want it ,  i want to add this code on a button click event.

```
Menu menu;
button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.helpp);
                item.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
```

this crashes my app kindly tell me how to do this as i have wasted 9 hours thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are probably getting `null pointer exception`, because you're accessing uninitialized field `menu`. Except that, Android's `Activity` class provides method `invalidateOptionsMenu()` which requests menu to be recreated.
Your activity class might look like:

```
boolean buttonClicked = true;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (buttonClicked) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.helpp).setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Button listener:

```
button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        buttonClicked = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```